# How to make ggplot2 exclude zero values in this plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following `R` codes running in `RStudio`, with the output also shown below:

```
df2  %>%
  ggplot(aes(
    x = JANUARY,
    y = value,
    fill = JANUARY,
    group = year
  )) +
  geom_col(
    position = position_dodge(.65),
    width = .5
  ) +
  geom_text(aes(
    y = value + max(value) * .03,
    label = round(value * 100) %>% str_c('%')
  ),
  position = position_dodge(.65)
  ) +
  geom_text(aes(
    y = y_pos,
    label = str_remove(year, 'X')
  ),
  color = 'white',
  angle = 90,
  fontface = 'bold',
  position = position_dodge(0.65)
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    breaks = seq(0, .9, .1),
    labels = function(x) round(x * 100) %>% str_c('%')
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(
    rgb(47, 85, 151, maxColorValue = 255),
    rgb(84, 130, 53, maxColorValue = 255),
    rgb(244, 177, 131, maxColorValue = 255),
    rgb(112, 48, 160, maxColorValue = 255),
    rgb(90, 48, 100, maxColorValue = 255)
  )) +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = .5),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = rgb(.9, .9, .9)),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    legend.position = 'none'
  ) +
  xlab('') +
  ylab('') +
  ggtitle('Month of JANUARY (as at 01 January)')
```

Output is:

[image: column chart]

As you can see, the value "0%" under "D-Final" is causing the labels inside the bars to disappear below the `x-axis`.

I want to remove the "0%" and get the labels back into position inside the bars. How can I modify my codes to achieve this?

Data (`df2`) added:

```
JANUARY year  value y_pos
   <fct>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 D-150   X2016  0.26 0.12 
 2 D-90    X2016  0.49 0.21 
 3 D-60    X2016  0.63 0.265
 4 D-30    X2016  0.73 0.325
 5 D-Final X2016  0.81 0    
 6 D-150   X2017  0.28 0.12 
 7 D-90    X2017  0.5  0.21 
 8 D-60    X2017  0.64 0.265
 9 D-30    X2017  0.77 0.325
10 D-Final X2017  0.82 0    
11 D-150   X2018  0.33 0.12 
12 D-90    X2018  0.51 0.21 
13 D-60    X2018  0.62 0.265
14 D-30    X2018  0.77 0.325
15 D-Final X2018  0.78 0    
16 D-150   X2019  0.24 0.12 
17 D-90    X2019  0.42 0.21 
18 D-60    X2019  0.53 0.265
19 D-30    X2019  0.65 0.325
20 D-Final X2019  0    0
```

Comment: Does `df2 %>% filter(value > 0.01) %>%` in the first line help? Otherwise, please add [your data to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1320535) through `dput`.

Comment: Thanks. I have added the data "df2" to the question.

Comment: Yes the code you provided eliminates the zero values in the column chart but the position of my labels inside the bars for "D-Final" remain the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really about 0%, at least this point. Position of the labels is predefined and given by `y_pos`, so you may simply alter it yourself with, e.g.,

```
df2$y_pos[df2$JANUARY == "D-Final"] <- 0.4
```

As to remove 0%, the first line could be replaced by

```
df2 %>% filter(value > 0.01) %>%
```

This gives

[image]

Apparently `y_pos` was defined with

```
df2 %>% group_by(JANUARY) %>% mutate(y_pos = min(value) / 2)
```

Hence, as to avoid this issue, in this case (since all the other value by group are similar) you may instead use

```
df2 %>% group_by(JANUARY) %>% mutate(y_pos = max(value) / 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

in the first line you can filter df2 to get all non-zero values using `df2 %>% filter(value!=0)`

Comment: It removes the zero but I still have the labels inside the bars for "D-Final" not appearing fully.